# Actions on Google - My alpha tester could not access my action

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Initially, I built up a test agent on DialogFlow console according to the document, and it works well on the Actions On Google which is a simulator of Google Assistant on mobile devices.

Then, I deployed it through the **Release** in the left menu as you can see the pic attached.

[deployed successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lk1ci.png)

After that, I added some Alpha Testers including my colleague and sent my opt-in link to my colleague, besides, I granted them all the viewer permission in IAM.

However, problem appeared. It didn't work well on my testers’ phone(IOS 10+)  but only worked well on developer's account(mine). When they opened the link I sent to them, and clicked **send to devices**, then clicked the notification on top of the screen.

[send to device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BMaw.jpg)

The result is shown as below.

[Google Assistant didn't respond to "Talk to mytest app"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lW1bp.jpg)

In my case the command was set as "Talk to hello qad", and it did work well on my phone used the developer account.

[developer account works well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uw5qT.jpg)

If my tester input the text "Talk to hello qad", it just replied some direct searching results not hello qad diaglog.

To recap:

- My action has already been in "deployed" status for couple of days
- I've added the tester accounts in whitelist and give them "Viewer" permission in IAM
- Testers could see the action directory page in devices by open opt-in link, but they couldn't see the "I'm In" button and couldn't access the action

Appreciate for any help or advice

Comment: As stated in question, you first deployed the test version and then added alpha testers. You might have to publish new alpha version "after adding the testers" and then wait till you get "deployed" status on the new alpha release too...

Comment: I currently have a similar problem where over the weekend my alpha tester on iOS was able to see the listing but unable to invoke the app. Working on my developer account, app is considered "deployed" in console. My suggestion is send feedback from the console to least inform them of a possible issue

Comment: I have the same issue, also using iPhone here. The opt-in link shows the directory listing, but there is no "Opt-In Button" or anything really which lets you opt-in.

Answer (score 3):

During my project development, I also faced a similar issue. This is how managed to do testing:

- Made sure all Google Accounts were created with the US as the country.
- Through IAM, share AoG project with the tester's Google accounts.
- All testers to open the shared simulator link in their browsers. This is important!
- Test the app on browser first using the simulator.
- Once tested, use any device with the whitelisted Google Accounts.

US country was required for my use case as I was having Transaction API in my Assistant. I had to also mock my location to the US on mobile for testing US specific features.

See if the above steps help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually, before I did what you suggested, I had contacted a member of Actions on Google Support, I sent him my opt-link of my agent and added him to my alpha tester list, well, it turned out that it ran really well on his phone which is based on Android. And after I did what you suggested, it seemed that it still didn't work on my iPhone when logged in other tester account. Only one of my colleagues can tested my agent successfully on his iPhone. Though still confused, anyway thanks for your advice.

Comment: iPhones have issues. Some works some not. Use Android phones.

Comment: I face issues on Android too

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Google and this is what they said:

You have to copy the link to the notes app, and then click it and in the prompt, choose “Open in Assistant”.

Full text:

Please ensure that the opt-in link is opened in Google Assistant app and not in a browser. At this time, Google Assistant app is only available in USA. For opening an opt-in link in iPhone or any iOS device, please follow the steps below:

```
1. Download the Assistant App in App Store

2. Log in using the included account for Beta testing
3. Copy the opt-in URL to Notes app

4. Hold press the opt-in link then select 'Open in "Assistant"'. Google Assistant and App page in the Assistant Directory will be displayed.

5. Scroll down the page until you see the "Become a Beta tester" section

6. Click the I'M IN button

7. Test the Action
```

This does not work for me, probably because I am not in the US. However, the app is of course available here.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue with Google Actions/Dialog Flow. Here is how I resolved it...

1. Share the app from within DialogFlow to the test user
2. Copy the current DialogFlow URL from the address bar
3. Launch an Incognito Window
4. Paste the DialogFlow URL from Step 2 in the address bar
5. Log into DialogFlow using the test account
6. At the [Standard Google Account Access Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnML0.png) Allow the access so your Google Action can talk to DialogFlow.

I couldn't find this documented anywhere and wasted about 8 hours figuring it out.

Answer (score 1):

For me it only worked after I shared with the user the link to test on desktop that look likes: https://console.actions.google.com/project/XXX/simulatorcreate?isDeepLink the one you can get the the console menu on the sharing icon.

I asked him to login with same google email he has opted-in in Google Assistant and
to verify if when mouse over on the devices icon on the menu he would see "Testing on Device: Enabled
You currently are able to test your Actions on all
Assistant devices connected to "xxxx@gmail.com". "

Then he could invoque almost right away the alpha version of the BOT.

All that considering that he has already clicked on the opt-in link, I had added his emails as a Alpha tester and I had also added him as a Viewer on Permissions at the console admin https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a developer of the project, the test version is enabled by default on your device. If you want to access the alpha and beta versions, make sure to disable the ‘Testing on device’ option on the Actions Console simulator.

Answer (score 0):

#### Add users before deploying alpha release

I feel obligated to copy dedman's comment on your question here, since his solution worked for me and is the only one directly addressing the problem at hand: **an alpha release is not available to testers you have added after deploying the release.**

> As stated in question, you first deployed the test version and then added alpha testers. You might have to publish new alpha version "after adding the testers" and then wait till you get "deployed" status on the new alpha release too... – dedman

I was encountering this exact problem with the Alpha release of my Action, i.e. assistant not responding on alpha users devices, even though I had deployed the release, shared the opt-in link with users and had them click on it to opt-in.  Deploying a new alpha release after users had clicked the opt-in link solved the problem and the action is now responding correctly for all users.

#### IAM Viewer status is not mandatory

By the way, I can also confirm your suspicion that "Viewer" permission in IAM is not needed for alpha users to have access to your release - they only need to opt-in before you deploy a new release.